# TypeError: get() takes no keyword arguments

Tags: python

I tried some code like:

```
converted_comments[submission.id] = converted_comments.get(submission.id, default=0)
```

where `converted_comments` is a `dict`. But I get an error that says:

```
TypeError: get() takes no keyword arguments
```

The [documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#dict.get) seems to show that `dict.get` does take an argument named `default`.

> `get(`*key*[, *default*]`)`
>
> Return the value for *key* if *key* is in the dictionary, else *default*. If *default* is not given, it defaults to `None`, so that this method never raises a `KeyError`.

What is wrong, and why doesn't it work like I expect?

Comment: a bit offtopic, but you can use `defaultdict` from the `collections` module to achieve the same functionality.

Comment: people might hate me for suggesting this but I've being doing this for range since I have a terrible memory of what the order of things are. Imo this shouldn't be a problem so I'm fixing it: `range(*{'start':0,'stop':10,'step':2}.values())`

Answer (score 40, accepted):

The error message says that `get` takes no keyword arguments but you are providing one with `default=0`

```
converted_comments[submission.id] = converted_comments.get(submission.id, 0)
```

Comment: I just realized would have seen this if I'd scrolled down. Oops! Thanks!

Comment: I prefer the other answer because you  do not address the fact that this is a surprising restriction, as usually python functions allow keyword arguments. The other answer addresses this.

Answer (score 198):

Due to the way the Python C-level APIs developed, a lot of built-in functions and methods don't actually have names for their arguments. Even if the documentation calls the argument `default`, the function doesn't recognize the name `default` as referring to the optional second argument. You have to provide the argument positionally:

```
>>> d = {1: 2}
>>> d.get(0, default=0)
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
TypeError: get() takes no keyword arguments
>>> d.get(0, 0)
0
```

Comment: You hinted, but didn't say explicitly: python functions usually allow arbitrary named arguments. The C-level API is an exception to the rule.

Comment: Thanks, although it's more annoying if I want to debug current code

Comment: Wow I used python for 7 years, and I never knew there were functions that don't take keyword arguments. That's so strange, surely the interpreter could maintain a dictionary of builtin functions and their argument names, so that it could accept keyword arguments with nearly zero runtime cost? (The only cost would be during the generation of bytecode, and it would be very small.)

Comment: @max: Parameter names can't be resolved at compile time, because what callable you're calling can't be resolved at compile time. Making it a compile-time thing wouldn't intrinsically make all C functions and methods take keyword arguments, anyway; either way, people would have to go through and add all the missing parameter name metadata by hand, and they could (but don't) do that under the current design.

Answer (score 12):

Many docs and tutorials, for instance https://www.tutorialspoint.com/python/dictionary_get.htm, erroneously specify the syntax as

`dict.get(key, default = None)`

instead of

`dict.get(key, default)`

Comment: `dict.get(key, default)` would also be an incorrect signature, as it shows the second argument as required.

Comment: maybe this way is clearer `dict.get(key[, default])`?

Comment: this solves my problem, thanks
it was foolist for me to do so somedays ago