# Default dict keys to avoid KeyError

Tags: python, json, csv, dictionary, keyerror

I parsed some JSON data, creating `bb_json`, and am trying to write CSV data based on it to `csv_writer`. I have this code:

```
for product in bb_json['products']:
    row = []

    row.append(product['sku'])
    if product['name']:
        row.append(product['name'])
    else:
        row.append("")
    if product['description']:
        row.append(product['description'])
    else:
        row.append("none")
    row.append(product['image'] + " ")
    if product['manufacturer']:
        row.append(product['manufacturer'])
    else:
        row.append("UNKNOWN")
    row.append(product['upc'])
    row.append(product['department'])
    row.append(product['class'])
    row.append(product['subclass'])
    
    csv_writer.writerow(row)
```

But I get a `KeyError` from the attempts to read data from `product`, because many of these values are unpopulated. How can I fill in default values in the `row`?

Answer (score 80, accepted):

You can use `your_dict.get(key, "default value")` instead of directly referencing a key.

Comment: Thanks for assisting.  That line would be inserted before the for loop, or iteratively within?

Comment: Whenever you'd normally access a key.  So when you go to get the product's name instead of `row.append(product['name'])` you would use `row.append(product.get('name', 'value if name key doesn't exist'))`

Comment: Thanks, that seemed to work!!  One final point:  I'm now getting a nonetype error for one of the fields (manufacturer).  The if clause for 'name' works well, but a similar syntax yields the dreaded KeyError once again.

Comment: Don't use `None` for the default value. In your code you're setting it to `""` if the value doesn't exist. So try `row.append(product.get('name', ''))` Which will append the value for `name` if it exists, or an empty string if it doesn't.

Comment: Notice that "dict" shouldn't be the name of your dictionary, since "dict" is a reserved built-in symbol in Python

Answer (score 9):

Don't use the "default" argument name. For example, if we want 1.0 as default value,

```
rank = dict.get(key, 1.0)
```

For more details:
[TypeError: get() takes no keyword arguments](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24463202/typeerror-get-takes-no-keyword-arguments)

Answer (score 9):

If you can't define a default value and want to do something else (or just omit the entry):

```
if key in dict:
    rank = dict[key]
else:
    # do something or just skip the else block entirely
```

Answer (score 2):

You could use syntax like this: `product.get("your field", "default value")`