# How to set default values in list of dictionary python?

Tags: python, aws-lambda, python-3.6

I have a list of dictionary accepting the user Input values as shown below:

```
def get_params(app_name):
    return [
           {'Key':'Path', 'Value': event['Path']},
           {'Key':'TargetType', 'Value': event['Target']},
           {'Key': 'Owner', 'Value': event['Owner']}
          ]

def lambda_handler(event,context):
     params = get_params('hello')
     print(params)
```

How to set default values for `Path` as `/` and `TargetType` as `True`for example, so that if user has not passed any value, it picks the default value?

Edit: Wanted to have default value set for `Path`, in case the value of `event['Path']` is not found or is null.

Comment: What is a "lambda event"? All I see is a function? Are you using some framework?

Comment: Sorry for using the term lambda event. Edited the question. Basically wanted to set default values in `get_params` function for all the keys.

Comment: From the parameters, I assume this is an AWS lambda function, which has nothing to do with a python lambda; I've updated the tag.

Comment: @DanielRoseman Thanks for that. Ya I was intending to add aws-lambda as a tag.

Comment: This actually has nothing to do with AWS Lambda, aside from the fact that AWS Lambda calls the `lambda_handler()` event. After that, it is all standard Python.

Comment: Yeah ! Hence added that as edit , basically wanted to know how to set default values in list of dictionary . If it was just a dictionary, could have used ‘get’ and set default value . Now was wondering how to do in case of list of dictionary.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Python: default dict keys to avoid KeyError](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24814024/python-default-dict-keys-to-avoid-keyerror)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It appears that your requirements are:

- `get_params()` should return values from `event[]`
- Substitute default values if the values are not provided

You could use:

```
def get_params(app_name):
    return [
           {'Key':'Path', 'Value': event.get('Path', '/')},
           {'Key':'TargetType', 'Value': event.get('Target', True)},
           {'Key': 'Owner', 'Value': event['Owner']}
          ]
```

Comment: Thanks a lot John !! This is what I was looking for. I was trying to use `get` , but had got the syntax wrong inside a list of dictionary. Thanks again, this worked perfectly :+1:

Answer (score 2):

A python `dict` has two ways of addressing its values:

1. `events["path"]` - would raise an exception if `"path" not in events`
2. `events.get("path", "default")` - would return "default" if the key is missing

Comment: Thanks Uri ! This was what i was looking for. Probably, the way I put the question forward was confusing.