# Why can't I use named arguments in Python 2 for the functions from the standard library

Tags: python, python-2.7

Why can't I use named arguments in Python 2 in case of `str.split` function from the Python's standard library while I can use them for my own functions:

```
def foo(bar=''):
  pass

foo(bar='str')
```

Comment: Some built-in functions support keyword arguments http://stackoverflow.com/a/24463222/2301450

Comment: And some don't support them, at least in Python 2.7. In Python 2.5, `str.split` has the keyword argument `sep`.

Comment: The second-listed answer on the dupe explains that this is a limitation of the C-level API.