# How to use get function with a default value on a dictiontionary with tuples as keys?

Tags: python

Basically I have a dictionary that uses a tuple as a key. I want to utilize the get() function so that I can assign a default value if the key does not exist in the dictionary. However, I get a TypeError: get() takes no keyword arguments error when I attempt to do this. Here is my code that raises an exception:

```
dict = {('a', 'b'): 10}
dict.get(('a', 'b'), default = 0)
```

How can I accomplish what I am trying to do?

Comment: `dict.get(('a', 'b'), 0)`

Comment: wow this words. So just by removing the keyword default makes this construction work?

Comment: Yes, and that's exactly what the error message is telling you. There are also cases with no positional arguments, that require keywords.

Comment: Does this answer your question:https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24463202/typeerror-get-takes-no-keyword-arguments/24463222?

Comment: Yes it does. I understand where I messed up now. Thank you all

Answer (score 2):

Use:

```
dict.get(('a', 'b'), 0)
```

The second parameter has no keyword (see [python documentation on standard types](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#typesmapping))

> get(key[, default])
>
> ```
> Return the value for key if key is in the dictionary, else default. If default is not given, it defaults to None, so that this
> ```
>
> method never raises a KeyError.